# How to prevent scrollview to scroll after reach ends

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview

In my react native project, I have a screen that wrapped its contents in a scrollview.

The problem happen in ios only, and it is that I could scroll up even if it's already at the most top edge (contentOffset.y = 0) so the contentOffset.y could be less than zero and an empty space appeared; it back again to zero offset but I want to prevent that behavior at all. How could I do that

Update
If that is not possible, could I at least prevent bouncing up and down while dragging a slider left and right that wrapped inside the scrollview ? I tried to set directionalLockEnabled to true but it doesn't help

Comment: It's not a problem, it is a common iOS behaviour and the user would like to have this, anyway it is called bounce, maybe it could help you to find your answer.

Comment: @SaintThread thank you